# How can I read Javascript variable with Awesomium? c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, awesomium

I want to read a Javascript value from the page, but how?

```
    std::string jscript("[appdata]");
    JSValue value = view_->web_view()->ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(WSLit(jscript.c_str()), WSLit(""));
    JSArray& arr = value.ToArray();
    std::string appdata = arr[0].ToString;
```

When I try to use this I get **Awesomium::JSValue::ToString: non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member**

tbh I have no idea where to put **&**

Answer (score 0):

My C++ is rather rusty but don't you need to add parentheses at the end?

```
std::string appdata = arr[0].ToString();
```

As it stands, the code seems to be trying to get a pointer to a member function ToString and assign it to std::string variable.

Comment: Well, I tried this and here is the result:

**Awesomium::WebString' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>

no suitable user-defined conversion from "Awesomium::WebString" to "std::string" exists**

Comment: So my observation was correct: you were assigning the function pointer instead of a value/object. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is the answer for the future wonderers:

```
    JSValue MyValue = view_->web_view()->ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(WSLit("appdata"), WSLit("")).ToString();
    WebString asd(MyValue.ToString());
    std::string appdata = ToString(asd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
std::string appdata = arr[0].ToString;
```

to

```
Awesomium::WebString appdata = arr[0].ToString();
```

As Mike Klimentiev said, you're assigning the method ToString to the variable appdata. When you add the parentheses, it makes a function call rather than a straight assignment of the function to the variable.

Also, when you add the parentheses, the compiler error message is telling you that it cannot convert the type "Awesomium::WebString" to type "std::string". At the very beginning of the line you have `std::string appdata` This declares a variable `appdata` of type `std::string`. However the method ToString() returns a type of `Awesomium::WebString`for which there is no conversion to the type `std::string`

EDIT:
@bugraarslan Based on experience, I would be wary of your workaround. There is no easy conversion between the two types, because they didn't write one. Usually, this means you can either use the type `Awesomium::WebString` or fight the library by using a familiar type namely, `std::string`. Libraries do not tire in their stubbornness, but do as you please

I don't have enough reputation to comment. So, I had to amend my answer instead.